# Passing Data to an open window|Capture window open event

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

Iam building a firefox extension using overlay js. If you click here http://cloud.feedly.com/#welcome and press the login button a pop up window will appear.

I want to pass some data to that window and use them.If it can't be done is there a way to capture the event before the window popup?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a very simple way to do something after that window loads, you can listen to DOMContentLoaded event and then check if you are on the desired page, like so:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    if (gBrowser.currentURI.spec.indexOf(URL_OF_SPECIFIC_WINDOW_YOU_WANT) != -1) {
        // Do your processing here
    }
}, false);
```

I'm doing the `indexOf` instead of `==` so you can put just some part of the page url in there and it will work.